# grep matching string regex powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

How to grep for a pattern matching from a text file?
I have a string like below.

```
2018-04-10 08:10:35 M2686678688 abc-jhg-jj-kjk
<accepted> M1236687688</accepted>
```

I am using like below:

```
Get-ChildItem $path\a.txt | Select-String "M(\d{10})"
```

Not sure how to get only the matching string from the above.
Desired output should be:

```
M2686678688 
M123668768
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, using Select-String to process the file.

It outputs MatchInfo objects for each match, and then you need the first one, and the capture group, and then the value that matched:

```
$values = select-string -Path "$path\a.txt" -Pattern 'M(\d{10})' |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is remove the capturing group and expand the value of the matches:

```
Get-ChildItem $path\a.txt |
    Select-String 'M\d{10}' |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    Select-Object -Expand Groups |
    Select-Object -Expand Value
```

If you have a varying number of digits after the "M" you may also want to adjust your expression to something like `M\d+`. If the number of digits must be in a specific range you could use a pattern `M\d{MIN,MAX}`, e.g. `M\d{5,}` for a string with at least 5 digits, or `M\d{7,15}` for a string with at least 7 and at most 15 digits.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using "\d{10}" which basically checks 10 time and in your second line sample its only 9 digits hence you are not able to get the second match.

Secondly instead of using get-childItem the same purpose is specified using the path parameter of Get-Content.
     Get-Content -Path a.txt | %{ [Regex]::Matches($*, "M([0-9]*)") } | %{ $*.Value }
 and you will get all the matching results.

Comment: give complete path if you are not on the same location Get-Content -Path $path\a.txt | %{ [Regex]::Matches($_, "M([0-9]*)") } | %{ $_
.Value }

Comment: Thank you, this is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

First, you pattern will never match the second value (`M123668768`) because you are looking for an `M` followed by 10 digits whereas the value only has 9. So if you want to match both values the correct regex-pattern would be:

```
M\d+
```

Now you can create a `Regex` object

```
$regex = [Regex]::new("M\d+")
```

and get all Matches

```
$regex.Matches("2018-04-10 08:10:35 M2686678688 abc-jhg-jj-kjk
<accepted> M123668768</accepted>")
```

To get only the Values of the Matches you can add `.Value`

```
$regex.Matches("2018-04-10 08:10:35 M2686678688 abc-jhg-jj-kjk
<accepted> M123668768</accepted>").Value
```

Comment: Thank you Bergmann but I need to read the text from file and process it